# WickedPDF shows only grey dot when loading image from S3 in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, wicked-pdf

In my Rails app my users can upload images via carrierwave and image magic. Works great.

Now I am trying to generate a PDF with the image so in my download.pdf.erb I have

```
<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag('https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/uploads/image/image/1/thumb_71fxg4BPTuL._SY450_.jpg') %>
```

In my browser I can access the URL and see the image but in my PDF file on production mode I only see a grey dot. On AWS the permission for the bucket and image are all public.

On my local server the PDF loads with the image.

Any ideas?

Comment: On some hosts, `wkhtmltopdf` needs SSL to load images over HTTPS, it's possible that's what's going on here. Does it work with an HTTP link? On Heroku, there's this that supposedly fixes it: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/741 Otherwise, you can download the file with ruby, and serve it from within your app, if that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks, the comment lead me to the answer. On my Heroku stack (the newest one) I have to load images without HTTPS...now it works

Comment: could you please post what you ended up doing as an answer to help others find this in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I solved and, although it's a workaround at might compromise the security of the app, here is what I did:

My app serves via HTTPS but still, removing the HTTPS from the S3 files solved the problem.

```
image_url.gsub('https','http')
```